# Getting Path of File Inside Jar

Tags: java, image, jar

I'm trying to access an image located inside of a running jar.

Here is my code:

```
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
            getClass().getResource("/res/sprites/"));
```

The code above works absolutely fine.

The problem I'm having is a is converting it into a readable String to be used by a BufferedImage objet.

Here is my code: (pathRelativeToThis is a String)

```
Image path = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
            getClass().getResource("/res/sprites/" + pathRelativeToThis));
    String image = "file://" + path.toString();

    URL url = new URL(image);
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
```

This doesn't work and gives `javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't get input stream from URL!` as an error.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: `Class.getResource()` returns URL. `ImageIO.read(URL)` accepts URLs. Why do you want to convert it to `String` in between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this and work with stream directly:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/sprites/" + pathRelativeToThis);
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(is);
is.close();
```

Also have you tried to pass resource URL to ImageIO directly?

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/res/sprites/" + pathRelativeToThis)
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
```

Comment: second line refers to url - can one use a stream instead there? Thought there might be an extra trick needed?

Answer (score 1):

Remove path and just try to do this

```
String image = "file://" + getClass().getResource("/res/sprites/" + pathRelativeToThis);
URL url = new URL(image);
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
```